# Google Natural language REST API returns error 400 Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"document\": "

Tags: ajax, rest, nlp, google-cloud-platform

I am using google natural language to detect entity sentiment, sending ajax call to https://language.googleapis.com/v1/documents:analyzeEntitySentiment always returns error 400, my ajax call is as below,

{

APIKEY = '**********************';

```
    $.ajax({
        type        : "POST",
        url         : "https://language.googleapis.com/v1/documents:analyzeEntitySentiment?key="+APIKEY,
        ContentType : "application/json",
        data        : {
                        "document": JSON.stringify(
                                      {  "type":"PLAIN_TEXT",
                                          "content":"Nature is so beautiful" 
                                      }),
                        "encodingType":"UTF8" 
                    },
        success     : function(_result){

            if (_result) {    
                alert('SUCCESS');
            }else{
                alert('ERROR');
            }
        },
        error       : function(_result){
            alert(_result);
        }
    });
```

and error :

```
"code": 400,
"message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"document\": Cannot bind query parameter. 'document' is a message type. Parameters can only be bound to primitive types.",

"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",

"details": [
  {

    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
    "fieldViolations": [
      {
        "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"document\": Cannot bind query parameter. 'document' is a message type. Parameters can only be bound to primitive types."
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

as mentioned in document https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/rest/v1/documents/analyzeEntitySentiment "document" should be used as request body data.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Remove the JSON.Stringify call on the document. Your payload is already in string format.

```
 data        : {
                    "document": {  "type":"PLAIN_TEXT",
                                      "content":"Nature is so beautiful" 
                                  },
                    "encodingType":"UTF8" 
                },
```